# Redirect component is rendered but won't change history object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I am having this issue. When login is successful, I am setting `redirect` property of redux state to path I want to redirect to. My redux state is being updated correctly. In my Auth component, I can see that Redirect component is rendered and url in browser changes to that specific path. Yet in my parent component, when I access `history` object, it still shows the old url and therefore `Switch` component picks wrong path.

```js
render() {
  console.log(this.props.history.location);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{this.props.redirect}</p>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" render={() => <p>Home page</p>} />
        <Route path="/" component={Auth} exact />
      </Switch>     
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here, the output of `console.log` is `/` (the old path), `this.props.redirect` shows `/home` (which is the correct new path).

Here is the Auth component.

```js
let authRedirect = null;
if (this.props.isAuthenticated && this.props.redirect) {
  authRedirect = <Redirect to={this.props.redirect} />
}

console.log(authRedirect)

return (
  <div className="Auth">
    {authRedirect}
    {form}
  </div>
);
```

Console logging `authRedirect` shows that it holds the correct `Redirect` component once the users has been logged in (both `isAuthenticated` and `redirect` values that are obtained from redux are correct).

Can you tell me where the mistake is? Why is the `history` object not being updated even though everything else seems to behave correctly? (Redux state changes - it is clearly visible in the App component when it is rendered the second time, Redirect is rendered and url in my browser is changed to correct one)

UPDATE:

When I place `console.log` into `componentDidUpdate` method in App component, it shows the correct value of `this.props.history.location`.

UPDATE 2:

When I place logs into `render` and `componentDidUpdate` methods in both `App` and `Auth` components and hit Login button, this is the result.
Both `App` and `Auth` are rendered while `history.location.pathname` is still set to `/auth` but redux state is correctly set to `/`. `history.location.pathname` is correctly set only after the components have been rendered in `componentDidUpdate`.

```js
[APP RENDER], location.pathname: /auth, redux - redirect: /
[AUTH RENDER], location.pathname: /auth, redux - redirect: /
[AUTH UPDATE], location.pathname: /, redux - redirect: /
[APP UPDATE], location.pathname: /, redux - redirect: /
```

Comment: does your route component get refreshed after the redux store update?

Comment: @aravind_reddy The whole parent component where the Route component sits is refreshed with the correct redux state.

Comment: so in your console.log it gives the same value twice ?

Comment: @aravind_reddy exactly,  console logging `this.props.history.location` gives the same value twice

Comment: Are you using withRouter component/wrapper for your connected component?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Yes, both `App` and `Auth` components are wrapped by `withRouter`

Comment: Which version of react-router did you use?

Comment: @PouyaJabbarisani version 4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

in the destination page, you can get the updated pathname from history listen

```
this.props.history.listen(location => {
  if (location.pathname !== this.props.location.pathname) {
    this.props.location.pathname = location.pathname;
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
});
```

in my case, I created the state URL and update it from componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.history.listen(location => {
        if(location) {
            this.setState({
                url: location.pathname
            })    
        }
    });
}
```